# XML elements to array of bool

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following XML

```
<Appointment>
    <FollowupDays>
        <boolean>true</boolean>
        <boolean>true</boolean>
        <boolean>false</boolean>
        <boolean>true</boolean>
    </FollowupDays>
</Appointment>
```

I want a `bool[]` loaded from the elements of `FollowupDays`. The `boolean` elements are are items in the array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider using `XElement` which is supported `.NET 3` and above, you can consider using this:

```
XElement xElement = XElement.Load("path/to/your/xml");
bool[] followupDays = xElement
                        .Decendents("FollowupDays")
                        .First()
                        .Select(b => 
                            Convert.ToBoolean(b.Value))
                        .ToArray();
```